# Rationale behind render :new instead of redirect_to new for POST create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Given a rails RESTful controller

```
class WidgetsController
  def new
    @widget = Widget.new
  end

  def create
    @widget = Widget.new(params[:widget])
    render :new and return unless w.save

    redirect_to widget_path(@widget)
  end
end
```

Other than to capture the parameters and render validation messages why is the convention to `render :new` instead of `redirect_to new_widget_path` if validation fails?

As URL will alter from `/widgets/new` to `/widgets` if validation fails doesn't this break the concept of REST?

Comment: if you redirect, you're losing the params array, and you can't pre-fill the values in the fields

Comment: Yeah I understand about losing the params hash if there is a redirect. What I want to know is is there any reason other than that for breaking REST? (if it breaks it at all)

Answer (score 2):

Render will not call the controller action, so the instance variables that you have set in the create action will be taken to the new view.

this means that any validation errors persist in the new view...

redirect_to would run the controller action for new, and therefore create a new instance of your model... and you would loose the errors...

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Could you do this instead of rendering the new action?

```
   flash[:thing] = params[:thing]
   redirect_to new_thing_path
```

Then in new

```
   @thing = Thing.new(flash[:thing] || params[:thing])
```

This honestly seems nicer to me because otherwise if you have *any* logic in your controller that is required to render the new/edit actions, you have to repeat that logic (or create some before_filter or something) in update/create.   I realize this involves one more request but aside from that it seems simple and safer to code (apart from the fact that you are breaking rails conventions) and it gives the user a valid url that is always the same for looking at/doing the same thing.

If they refresh they'll lose their values but that is true of any form before being submitted.   And that seems to make more sense to me than refreshing resulting in a resubmit warning which is pretty strange.  How is a user supposed to clear the form for example?

This rails-ism has always bugged me.  Are there are any serious issues with this that I'm not considering?   Do other application frameworks all do the same?

Answer (score 0):

The thing with render is that it will not cause another request to be generated. It will go to the corresponding view and display it. With redirect, however, a redirect request to the browser will be generated, which will cause another request to your server.